# What causes this component was created without expected prop error in my Svelte app?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-2

I am working on a small Todo app in Svelte for learning purposes (Im new to Svelte).

In App.svelte I import the `TodoItem` component loop a `todos`array:

```
import TodoItem from './TodoItem.svelte';
//more code

{#each todos as t, index}<TodoItem t/>{/each}
```

In `TodoItem.svelte` I  have:

```
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    export let index;
    export let t;
    export let id;
    export let title;
    export let completed;
    
    //more code here
</script>

<tr>
    <td>{index + 1}</td>
    <td class="{t.completed == true ? 'completed' : ''}">{t.title}</td>
    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" checked="{t.completed}" on:change={completeTodo(t.id)}></td>
    <td class="text-right">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button on:click="{() => editTodo(t.id)}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</button>
            <button on:click="{deleteTodo(t.id)}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the console I get errors like this one `"<TodoItem> was created without expected prop 'index'"`, as this **[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/12cb6530a9bd46729751762e9979b610?version=3.23.2)** shows.

#### UPDATE

I replaced `{#each todos as t, index}<TodoItem t/>{/each}` with `{#each todos as t, index}<TodoItem t index={index} id={t.id} title={t.title} completed=false />{/each}` but I still get `undefined` for the title.

What is missing?

Comment: Change `t` from your component call to `t={t}`, but I don’t know why... You don’t need to provide `id`, `title` etc. because you’re already providing the whole object `t` to component and therefore inside the component you can access your object’s properties by using `t.id` or `t.title`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. In svelte shorthand code for defining the component property is `{t}` and your code you had `t`. That is the reason why `t` wasn’t defined inside your component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t provide `index` as a prop for component. Change your component call to `<Todoitem {t} {index}/>` or change `export let index` to `let index`, then the component doesn’t expect index-property.
EDIT: Fixed the shorthand codes to correct ones ie. `{t}`